# Strange problem with authentication on IBMMQ, it takes the running user ID

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I've got a strange problem when I perform a push of a message in a queue. I've configured my application to read userid/password from app.config. when the message is put on the queue I got the username of the user that has run the application and it's the one of the .config file.

The code I use to create the MQQueueManager is

```
  private static readonly Lazy<MQQueueManager> lazy =
        new Lazy<MQQueueManager>(() =>
        {
            var properties = new Hashtable();

            var container = ContainerWrapper.Container;

            IConfiguration configuration = container.GetInstance<IConfiguration>();

            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, configuration.GetValue<string>("HOST_NAME_PROPERTY"));
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, configuration.GetValue<int>("PORT_PROPERTY"));
            properties.Add(MQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, configuration.GetValue<string>("USER_ID_PROPERTY"));
            properties.Add(MQC.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, configuration.GetValue<string>("PASSWORD_PROPERTY"));
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, configuration.GetValue<string>("CHANNEL_PROPERTY"));


            MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(configuration.GetValue<string>("QUEUE_MANAGER_NAME"), properties);


            return queueManager;
        });
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your connection to run as the user ID and password provided on the connect, you must configure the queue manager to check the user ID and password and also you must configure the queue manager to adopt the validated user ID.

```
DISPLAY QMGR CONNAUTH
```

The value in the CONNAUTH field is the name of an AUTHINFO object. If it is blank, user ID and password checking is not enabled. Set it to an appropriate object name.

```
ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
```

Now look at the attributes of it.

```
DISPLAY AUTHINFO(name-from-connauth) ALL
```

If `ADOPTCTK` is set to `NO`, the the user ID will not be adopted as the connection's user ID, and so will not be seen in the message context.

```
ALTER AUTHINFO(name-from-connauth) AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) ADOPTCTX(YES)
```

If you had to make any alterations, you must now issue this command.

```
REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
```

Comment: Excuse me Morag, whate have I to pass as name-from-connauth ? the username?

Comment: The name that was displayed in the CONNAUTH field from the earlier DISPLAY command, or if blank, the name you set into it with the ALTER command.

Comment: Hello, I got this message AMQ8427: Valid syntax for the MQSC command:

  ALTER AUTHINFO( authinfo_name )
     AUTHTYPE( CRLLDAP | OCSP | IDPWOS | IDPWLDAP )

I'm using IBMMQ 8

Comment: Oops, my apologies - typo in command (did from memory). Have corrected answer.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to add another line to your properties.

Try (from memory so you will need to find the correct constant)
USE_MQCSP_USERNAME_PASSWORD This should be a boolean and should be set to yes....

Add this to your properties, then create the queue manager with those properties.

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is better to write a answer to something you specifically have knowledge of or have researched than to provide a answer to something you are not certain of (ex: from memory).  This is C# he is asking about and while it does have a property similar to what you mentioned, unlike Java it appears to be ignored and if the the USERID and PASSWORD are specified a MQCSP is generated no matter if the MQCSP property is set or not.  @Morag already provided the likely answer that MQ by default on the Qmgr after authenticating the ID/PW will use the user the process ran as for OAM checks.